# How to Properly Include an Angular App inside a PHP application

Tags: php, angular

Let's say I'm starting with a PHP application. On one of the pages on the site, there's a complex interactive app that I want to use Angular for. The problem is, I still want the header and footer of that page to match the rest of the site. I would love to be able to do something like this:

```
// main-template.php
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My Site-wide Header</title>
        <script src="site-wide-script.js"></script>
        <link href="site-wide-styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <?php if ($somevar == true) : ?>
            <?php echo "Yes, it has to be PHP"; ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="/home">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="/about">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="/contact">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </header>

        <!-- Drop entire Angular application here -->

    </body>
</html>
```

It somewhat works for me to just PHP `include` the Angular HTML file there, but that's pretty janky because, of course, the Angular `index.html` file already includes a `html`, `body`, etc. tags. Of course I could DOM parse the Angular file and fix all that before including...but I'd prefer a better solution.

In my searching I can't seem to find any officially recommended way of doing this. Actually I can't seem to find any examples of anyone doing this at all–all my searches just turn up people doing something similar with [AngularJS](https://angularjs.org/), not Angular. Is there any decent way to accomplish this with Angular?

Comment: You could use an `iframe`?

Comment: I don't love that solution due to (1) `iframe`s not respecting content size unless you use JS, (2) it causes the Angular app URL to be hidden.

Comment: You can try removing everything from `index.html` apart from the `<app-root>` tag before building the angular app. Seems to build okay

Comment: @user184994, I would like this solution a lot...but as soon as I remove the `<body>` tag from `index.html`, `ng build` starts putting the script tags at the top of the built `index.html`, resulting in runtime errors. Is there any way to customize where the Angular scripts are inserted during build?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be able to do what you want to do.

Here's the content of a index.html for a web based chat program I did as a HW project (the back end was much more fun...).

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>crap chat</title>
        <base href="/">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link href="bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    </head>
    <body class="m-a-1">
    <?php print("Hello World ".date("r",time())."<br />\n"); ?>
    <app></app>
<script type="text/javascript" src="inline.bundle.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="polyfills.bundle.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="styles.bundle.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="vendor.bundle.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="main.bundle.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

As long as you keep the same js file references and style sheets, styles (on `<body>` tag) etc. then you should be able to drop that in and toss in the `<app></app>` tag set just where you want it.

Just for giggles I renamed the file to `index.php` on my server, added a print statement to print date/time page was loaded, no issues.

Comment: I like where you're going with this, but the problem is that if I run `ng build --prod`, all of the source files get file names like `main.bc90171935f6ba7976ea.js`. With the random string of characters, it would be difficult/impossible to include the proper assets in my PHP template without having to update the `src`s every time I do a production build of my Angular app, which doesn't seem ideal.

Comment: You can set `"outputHashing"` to `"none"` in `angular.json`, which removes the suffix

Comment: @user184994 Nice! I didn't realize that. Thanks for saving the day!

Answer (score 2):

As of angular6, this should be possible using angular elements.

Your code would then simply be

```
// main-template.php
<html>
  <head>
      <title>My Site-wide Header</title>
      <script src="site-wide-script.js"></script>
      <link href="site-wide-styles" rel="stylesheet">
      <?php if ($somevar == true) : ?>
          echo "Yes, it has to be PHP";
      <?php endif; ?>
  </head>
  <body>
      <header>
          <ul>
              <li><a href="/home">Home</a></li>
              <li><a href="/about">About</a></li>
              <li><a href="/contact">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
      </header>
      <your-component-name></your-component-name>
  </body>
```

You can find a guide on how to create angular elements at https://angular.io/guide/elements - in principle, it is no harder than just creating a component

Comment: Unless you're going to show _how_ to do it, this should be a comment.

Comment: I disagree. The question is very broad and so is the answer. Creating an angular element is well documented so posting it in the answer will only create clutter.

Comment: Disagree all you want.  If you feel that a question is too broad to provide a proper answer, then you should vote/flag to close it as Too Broad.

Comment: If the question is simple, a simple answer is often the best.

Answer (score 2):

As someone might still come across this issue (like me), I want to share my solution:

As we are currently changing from a pure PHP page to an Angular approach, we need to include some basic php-stuff in the head of the index file of the Angular build process. Therefore, I added a **postbuild**-Step, which will automatically run after the build-step.

However, this step is running a node.js script which simply adds the php include we need in the index.php of the dist-Folder

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

const sourceDir = path.join('dist', 'path');
const phpTag = "<?php include_once './some.php' ?>\n";

const file = path.join(sourceDir, 'index.php');
fs.readFile(file, 'utf8', function (err, content) {
    if (err) throw err;

    if (!content.startsWith(phpTag)) {
        content = phpTag + content;

        fs.writeFile(file, content, 'utf8', function (err) {
            if (err) throw err;
        });
    }
});
```

and these are the entries of my `package.json`:

```
"scripts": {
    "build": "ng build",
    "postbuild": "node ./addPHPTag.ts",
```